# char* (containing null values) to std::string knowing length

Tags: c++, string, null, char

I'm working on a project where I have to transfer serialized data. The data is serialized using the [boost](http://www.boost.org) framework and then stored into a stringstream and finally to a std::string. To transmit the data, both the data (stored as char*, given!) and the length of the string are stored and can be extracted at the destination. However, when trying to extract the data, I only get empty strings. The ways I've tried it so far are:

```
C[i]=*new std::string(content, getDataChunk(), content.getDataLength());
```

or

```
C[i].append(content.getDataChunk(), content.getDataLength());
```

whereas std::string *C=new std::string[K], i < K.

```
char* p = content.getDataChunk(); 
        int l = content.getDataLength();
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            C[i].insert(j, p[j], 1);
        }
```

(This raises an exception right at the beginning - I guess because of NULL value(s)!?)

Obviously, strcpy() won't work since this uses a char* as destination which is NULL-terminated again...

Does anyone of you have an idea on how to solve this? I hope I'm not asking something that has been asked on a daily basis but in the sheer amount of answers it was quite hard to eliminate the chance ;)

Any of your hints are much much appreciated - TIA!

cheers,
Alex

Comment: If you save the value of the expression `* new something` you will have a memory leak.

Comment: `C[i]=*new std::string...` is a memory leak.  Change it to `C[i]=std::string...`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg right, thank you! I guess it worked using C[i]= std::string(...);, correct?

Comment: Thanks @DrewDormann - seems I was too slow :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just do

```
C[i] = std::string(content.getDataChunk(), content.getDataLength());
```

It will do the right thing, copying the complete string even if it has embedded `'\0'` characters in it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In this case I guess the error must be somewhere else, I just don't see where and thought it must be in this line...

Comment: I guess it won't do the right thing- if I try it with char *p= new char[11]; p="hell\0 world"; and then: cout << string(p,11); the output will be 'hell' (string length 11). or have I misunderstood anything?

Comment: @astriffe Tested with clang 3.3 (with libc++), and it works fine. What compiler and version of it are you using?

Comment: strange thing... I'm using g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1.. Do you know a workaround by chance? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @astriffe I just tested [this program](http://pastebin.com/WY46Q2Aa) with GCC 4.4.5, and it works fine. It says the length is 6 and prints the string as `hello`.

Comment: It remains weird - I pasted your code in my workspace and got the result < s.length() = 6
s = "hel >... Thanks a lot for your efforts!

Comment: For all who might read afterwards: According to an answer on the g++ mailing list, it seems to be an issue with std::cout rather than with std::string - if i use std::ofstream to take a look at the outcome, all characters are written correctly - i.e., it's not a std::string problem. Once more thanks Joachim for your help!

Comment: @astriffe Judging from your post on the mailing list, it's not clear that it's a problem with `std::cout` either; you can't judge from what gets printed on your terminal.  At the least, you need to pipe your test program through `hd` or something, so you can be really sure what's being output.  [Your example code (using `std::cout`) works properly for me (6 characters get output, including the embedded NUL), with g++ versions 4.4.7 through 4.8.]